# How do I get just the exceptions from ViewData.ModelState with Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I wrote the following code to extract out the exceptions along with a string key referencing the property from the ViewData.Modelstate property in ASP.Net MVC. I think it should be possible to do this with a Linq expression but it utterly flummoxed me.

```
       var exceptions = new Dictionary<string, Exception>();
       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> propertyErrorsPair in ViewData.ModelState)
       {
           foreach (var error in propertyErrorsPair.Value.Errors)
           {
               if (error.Exception != null)
               {
                   exceptions.Add(propertyErrorsPair.Key, error.Exception);
               }
           }
       }
```

So is there a Linq way of doing this? I'm guessing it might have something to do with SelectMany but as I say I couldn't quite work out how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, your code has a bug that when there are more than one exceptions in a single error, it fails when it wants to add the next one to the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the equivalent LINQ expression:

```
var result = ViewData.ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
   .Where(error => error.Exception != null)
   .Select(error => new KeyValuePair<string, Exception>(x.Key, error.Exception)));
```